# How do I install a *.bsx.gz file

Tags: software-installation, archive

I have an application I'd like to install via the command line which I download in `.bsx.gz` format, and I'm not sure what to do with it. I know it's supposed to be a self-extracting installer, but how do I go about installing it?

Answer (score 2):

OK This wasn't actually as hard as I thought.

The `.bsx` file is the self-extracting installer, so first you have to un-gzip it:

```
gzip -d /path/to/file.bsx.gz
```

Then give it executable permissions

```
sudo chmod +x /path/to/file.bsx
```

Then run it!

```
sudo /path/to/./file.bsx
```